# Get first letter of each word in a sentence except some keywords

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I think this one be tricky, but I wanted to hear if anybody might have a solution.

I need to create a formula which picks up the first letter in each of the words in a list of names, for instance:

> the university of electronic science and technology of china

UESTC ('the', 'of', 'and', 'a' to be avoided if possible)

What I tried so far:

```
=(LEFT(H2)&MID(H2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(H2&" "," ","#",1))+1,1)&MID(H2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(H2&" "," ","#",2))+1,1))&J2&M2
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Havnt come that far, something which partly works is:

=(LEFT(H2)&MID(H2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(H2&"  "," ","#",1))+1,1)&MID(H2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(H2&"  "," ","#",2))+1,1))&J2&M2

Comment: @Aabo, are you against using VBA? As you can see from these answers - excel doesn't have a good way to do this with inbuilt functions.

Comment: Hey nothing, Im using it for Microsoft PowerBI, which i dont think supports VBA? It supports DAX however..

Answer (score 2):

Good question! I think your best option is to create your own function using VBA. Add the code below to a new module in the VBA editor and you can use the function on your worksheets like this:

```
=FirstLetters(A1)
```

Which would return `UESTC`, as per your example

```
Function FirstLetters(str As String)
    Dim words As Variant
    Dim resultStr As String
    Dim i As Integer

    words = Split(str)
    For i = 0 To UBound(words)
        Select Case words(i)
            Case "the", "of", "and", "a"
                'ignore
            Case Else
                resultStr = resultStr & Left(words(i), 1)
        End Select
    Next i

    FirstLetters = UCase(resultStr)
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found a somewhat ridiculous answer which is basically concatenating a lot of ifs to loop through each word (VBA would be easier here). Below formula is for up to 9 words. If your strings have more you just have to add some `FIND(A1," ")+1`. Should the formula not work for you, delete the returns in it.

```
=IFERROR(UPPER(
IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1>=1,IFERROR(IF(SUM(--(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)={"the","of","a","and"})),"",LEFT(A1,1)),LEFT(A1,1)),"")&
IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1>=2,IF(SUM(--(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1),LEN(A1))-(FIND(" ",A1)+1))={"the","of","a","and"})),"",MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,1)),"")&
IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1>=3,IF(SUM(--(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1),LEN(A1))-(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1))={"the","of","a","and"})),"",MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1,1)),"")&
IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1>=4,IF(SUM(--(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1),LEN(A1))-(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1))={"the","of","a","and"})),"",MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1,1)),"")&
IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1>=5,IF(SUM(--(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1),LEN(A1))-(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1))={"the","of","a","and"})),"",MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1,1)),"")&
IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1>=6,IF(SUM(--(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),LEN(A1))-(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1))={"the","of","a","and"})),"",MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1,1)),"")&
IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1>=7,IF(SUM(--(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),LEN(A1))-(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1))={"the","of","a","and"})),"",MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1,1)),"")&
IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1>=8,IF(SUM(--(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),LEN(A1))-(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1))={"the","of","a","and"})),"",MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1,1)),"")&
IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1>=9,IF(SUM(--(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),LEN(A1))-(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1))={"the","of","a","and"})),"",MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1,1)),"")
),"")
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for this. It actual answer my request.. and I can kind of understand the formula also..

I can however see the names with only one word for instance:

'Alabama' should just reply back with 'A', in the above I get a blank cell? :/

THANKS, K

Comment: @Aabo I have adjusted above formula so that it should also work for one word strings now.

Comment: Do you also lose the A in Alabama from substituting "a"?

Comment: @CallumDA what do you mean? No letters are substituted and thus you wouldn't lose any.

Comment: @Aabo please note that I edited the second row in above formula where I missed something the first time. It should now work as intended.

Comment: Sorry, I should have read the formula - I was being lazy, saw substitute and presumed you removed unwanted letters using substitution. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Excel 2016 or 365, which has the CONCAT function available, the following formula will work with any length of string:

```
=LEFT(A1,1) & CONCAT(IF(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," the "," "), " of "," "), " a "," "), " and ", " "),ROW(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," the "," "), " of "," "), " a "," "), " and ", " ")),1)),1)=" ",MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," the "," "), " of "," "), " a "," "), " and ", " "),ROW(OFFSET($A$1,1,0,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," the "," "), " of "," "), " a "," "), " and ", " ")),1)),1),""))
```

Note that this is an array formula, which must be entered by double clicking into a cell, pasting the formula, then pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

It will always include the first letter of the first word, even if it is one of the key words to exclude. All other keywords are excluded. Generally the first letter of the first word should always be included, but if you need it removed as well, I can modify the formula further.

Comment: Nice, I have been waiting for something like `CONCAT`. Your formula is pretty neat, too, but doesn't work with `CONCATENATE` unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

use Substitute to remove what ever you want to discard.

syntax:

```
SUBSTITUTE(text, old_text, new_text, [instance_num])
```

Step2:

In any cell keep the value 1(suppose B1).

step 3:

use following formula to get first letter.

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>=B1,RIGHT(LEFT(A1,B1),1),"  ")
```

A1 is your input and B1 has value 1. if you want first letter. if you want second letter B1 value should be 2.. and so on.

If you want to have first word then:

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1)
```

Comment: if you want first word then. =LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1)